Running padd locally on my raspberry pi screen (via ssh command)
I've recently updated and rebuilt my raspberry pi to run Homebridge and pinhole but I can't figure out how to run padd on the raspberry pi screen for the life of me, I can run it on my local terminal but I'm trying to figure out how to make it run on the pi itself via ssh
